# Java "Browser Freeze" While Loading

Tags: java, php, html, browser, applet

OK this problem has been bugging me for so long.

Basically I made a signed Java applet that downloads a video from an url. The part of the code which calls the applet is below:

```
<?php
if(!empty($id)){
echo <<< END
<object codetype="application/x-java-applet" type="application/x-java-applet" code="downloader.class" archive="downloader.jar" height="0" width="0" align="center" cache_archive="downloader.jar" initial_focus="true">
<param name="v" value="$id"/>
<param name="u" value="$id"/>
<param name="ua" value="$agent"/>
It appears you do not have Java installed or it is disabled on your system.<br>
Please download it <a href="http://www.java.com/getjava/" class="link" target="_blank">here</a>.
</object>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
setTimeout("error()",120000);
});
</script>
END;
}
?>
```

I've properly declared all the variables, $id is the link to the video file so when my website receives a parameter via:

```
$id = ($_GET['url']);
```

If the url is not blank then it runs the java applet to download it.

So here is the problem. Whenever the java applet loads, the whole website freezes completely, you cannot scroll nor click any buttons; even hovering over a button won't yield a reaction. But after the applet loads which is about 5 to 10 seconds, the page unfreezes.

My questions are:

1) Is this "browser freeze" expected to happen?
2) Is there a way around this? I see websites like keepvid.com and savevid.com that also download videos, but have no 'browser freeze'. If there is something they are doing that I am not, I would really appreciate if someone tells me.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208161/java-applet-and-browser-freeze it depends on the version the Java JRE installed. What version are you running?

Comment: 1) Use [`deployJava.js`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html) to write the element needed to embed the applet (after checking minimum JRE). 2) At what URL can we see the applet? 3) Don't try to make a 0x0 applet.  Instead hide it using CSS (and only after it is proven to work correctly across a range of JREs and browsers on different OS').

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren I am using the latest version 7

Comment: @AndrewThompson I've tried deployJava.js it works but made my whole page blank.